# What is the library libz1.2.5 do in iOS?

Tags: ios

In reviewing an iOS program , I found a library called `libz1.2.3` or `libz1.2.5`.

What is the purpose of this library? Could any one explain why that library file is needed?

Answer (score 3):

[that's zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) - A Massively Spiffy Yet Delicately Unobtrusive Compression Library

it's used for compressing and uncompressing data (files, usually).  there's a list of [example applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib?elq=b83ae5450af94c40831999e48a6e5e66#Applications) in the wikipedia page.

it's standard for library files to start with "lib", followed by the name ("z" in this case) and then the version number (1.2.5).

[i'm kind of weirded out by the idea that no-one could answer this for 16 hours, so perhaps there's something i am completely missing here.  but i don't see what else it could possibly be.  it's a pretty famous, popular library.]